# How to check that Django model instance have preselected related data

Tags: python, django

Before Django 2.X I use this function for checking that `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` were prefetched to the Django model instance.

```
def ensure_related(obj, field):
    field_obj = obj._meta.get_field(field)

    if hasattr(obj, field_obj.get_cache_name()):
        return True
    return False
```

So for example

```
In [1]: permission = Permission.objects.last()

SELECT "auth_permission"."id",
       "auth_permission"."name",
       "auth_permission"."content_type_id",
       "auth_permission"."codename"
  FROM "auth_permission"
 INNER JOIN "django_content_type"
    ON ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id")
 ORDER BY "django_content_type"."app_label" DESC,
          "django_content_type"."model" DESC,
          "auth_permission"."codename" DESC
 LIMIT 1


In [2]: ensure_related(permission, 'content_type')

Out[2]: False

In [3]: permission = Permission.objects.prefetch_related('content_type').last()

SELECT "auth_permission"."id",
       "auth_permission"."name",
       "auth_permission"."content_type_id",
       "auth_permission"."codename"
  FROM "auth_permission"
 INNER JOIN "django_content_type"
    ON ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id")
 ORDER BY "django_content_type"."app_label" DESC,
          "django_content_type"."model" DESC,
          "auth_permission"."codename" DESC
 LIMIT 1


SELECT "django_content_type"."id",
       "django_content_type"."app_label",
       "django_content_type"."model"
  FROM "django_content_type"
 WHERE "django_content_type"."id" IN (1)


In [3]: ensure_related(permission, 'content_type')

Out[4]: True
```

But since Django 2.X this method always return `True`.

My questions is: how since Django 2.X implement this check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fields_cache` in `obj._state` (instance of [ModelState](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/base.py#L388))

```
>>> Car.objects.first()._state.fields_cache
{}

>>> Car.objects.prefetch_related('manufacturer').first()._state.fields_cache
{'manufacturer': None}
```

also works with lazy loading:

```
>>> car = Car.objects.first()
>>> car._state.fields_cache
{}
>>> car.manufacturer
>>> car._state.fields_cache
{'manufacturer': None}
```

so `ensure_related` should be like this:

```
def ensure_related(obj, field):
    return field in obj._state.fields_cache
```